# Tablelayout add textviews to tablerows

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my .xml with tablelayout...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:stretchColumns="*"

android:background="@drawable/s21" >


<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:text="Column 1 &amp; 2" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="140dip"
        android:layout_height="140dip"
        android:src="@drawable/bb"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bb" />



</TableRow>


<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="140dip"
        android:layout_height="140dip"
        android:src="@drawable/bb" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bb" />

</TableRow>
```

It looks like layout with 4 square imageviews... I want to add "name" on each square imageview... How can I do it in xml or programatically...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your each ImageView in a LinearLayout and add the TextView in a linear layout like this

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="140dip"
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:src="@drawable/bb"
     />
<TextView 
    android:text="Image desc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

your complete xml file will be like this

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:stretchColumns="*">


<TableRow
android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dip" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_span="2"
    android:text="Column 1 &amp; 2" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow 
android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="140dip"
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:src="@drawable/bb"
     />
<TextView 
    android:text="kiran"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="140dip"
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:src="@drawable/bb"
     />
<TextView 
    android:text="kiran"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
 </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>


<TableRow 
android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="140dip"
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:src="@drawable/bb"
     />
<TextView 
    android:text="kiran"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="140dip"
    android:layout_height="140dip"
    android:src="@drawable/bb"
     />
<TextView 
    android:text="kiran"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```